# Can't select JQuery correctly

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am trying to get a border added to the li when it is clicked. Here's my code.

```
<div class="noselect round" id="teach_edit_navigation_holster">
<ul id="teach_edit_navigation">
    <li id="edittab_one" class="teach_nav_roundleft">
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>       
    <li class="" id="edittab_two">
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>   
    <li class="" id="edittab_three">
        <span>Documents</span>
    </li>   
    <li class="" id="edittab_four">
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>   
    <li class="" id="edittab_five">
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>   
    <li class="teach_nav_roundright" id="edittab_six">
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>                   
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the Jquery. I want the whole li box to have a border on it, not the span. The code below is putting a border on a span. I don't know how to select the actual li. THank you!

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#edittab_two_s, #edittab_three_s, #edittab_four_s, #edittab_five_s, #edittab_six_s').hide();
//  $('#teach_edit_navigation').find('#edittab_one').css({
//            "background-color": "black"   // set highlight to first item on page "home"
//        });
});

$('#teach_edit_navigation_holster li').click(function () {
    var Vinfotab = this.id + '_s',
        $this = $(this);
    $('.edittab:visible').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#' + Vinfotab).fadeIn('fast');
        $('#teach_edit_navigation_holster li span').css({
            "border": "none" // reset all to default color
        });
        $this.find('span').css({
            "border-bottom": "1px solid black"   // set highlight to this element only
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get the code to work, though I admit I didn't read it *too* closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<li>` is represented by `$this`. This should work for you:

```
$('#teach_edit_navigation_holster li').css({ // !!! remove span
    "border": "none" // reset all to default color
});
$this.css({ // !!! remove .find('span')
    "border-bottom": "1px solid black"   // set highlight to this element only
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$this.find('span').css({
   "border-bottom": "1px solid black"   // set highlight to this element only
});
```

For this:

```
$this.css({
   "border-bottom": "1px solid black"   // set highlight to this element only
});
```